# File opened that is not a database file (but it is)

Tags: powershell, sqlite

I'm trying to pull information from an SQLite database using a Powershell script from a [Redgate article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/using-sqlite-powershell-sql-server/).

```
#I've installed the 64 bit System.Data.SQLite ADO.NET data provider in this directory 
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLite.NET\bin\x64\System.Data.SQLite.dll"
#I just create a connection to my existing database
$con = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection
# I then give it a simple connection string
$con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\Users\name\Desktop\fax.sqlite"# CHANGE THIS 
#and open the connection
$con.Open()
#We'll just start by creating a SQL statement in a command 
$sql = $con.CreateCommand()
$sql.CommandText = "select column from table;"
# we now execute the SQL and return the results in  a dataset
$adapter = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter $sql
#we create the dataset
$data = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
#and then fill the dataset
[void]$adapter.Fill($data)
#we can, of course, then display the first one hundred rows in a grid
#(1..100)|foreach{$data.tables[0].Rows[$_]}|out-gridview #-Title 'Authors and books'
```

I viewed the database using SQLite DB Browser (didn't need a password to open). However, whenever I use this script I get the below error:

> Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "File opened that is
> not a database file file is encrypted or is not a database" At
> C:\Users\name\Desktop\query sqlite db.ps1:9 char:1
>
> - $con.Open()
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SQLiteException
>   ```

Comment: Can you open and query the database with the standard sqlite3.exe command line program?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have all the libraries in place, to import the assemblies you need to use the Add-Type command:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\System.Data.SQLite\2010\bin\System.Data.SQLite.dll"
```

To connect to the database using the ADO.NET protocol, you need to create a SQLiteConnection object with the proper connection string:

```
$connection_details = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection
$connection_details.ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\database\test.db"
```

Your `$con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\Users\name\Desktop\fax.sqlite"` is having issue. It is expecting a proper DB connection but instead it is getting a string statement.

Comment: Hi, yes, I do have the ado.net provider downloaded from here and installed in the location specified in the script (https://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/). Can you point me to some resources to convert a string to an actual DB connection. I don't see any difference between my connection string and other examples I have seen. I completely believe you, I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @scarr030: NOthing much. Instead of that string you are mentioning in the connectionstring, you need to specify the `.db` full path . Rest all remains same

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when running a 32-bit dll on a 64-bit system.

If you are running a 64-bit Windows system then download *sqlite-netFx46-static-binary-x64-2015-1.0.116.0.zip* from https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki
and extract the contents to C:\Program Files\System.Data.SQLite\2010\bin\

Then run this command once or place it in your PowerShell script before making your connection object:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\System.Data.SQLite\2010\bin\System.Data.SQLite.dll"
```